# Logic for searching documents

Tags: full-text-search, logic

In the present age and time, we have tons of information for everything. Sometimes, the information is huge and not digitized. What logical formation would you develop to find specific information from a number of similar manuals so as to give the user the information in gist in real time. The user need not read through all the document. 
Do you first convert the documents into similar structure? Any suggestions? 
**EDIT:** 
 *I know this is some kind of text search problem.* 
  Let me present an example so that the question becomes a little focused:
**MANUAL1: (for California)**

```
Table of content 
...

Precautions:
1.) The operator must use synthetic gloves to handle chemicals
...
```

**MANUAL2: (for Minesotta)**

```
Table of content
...
Precautions:
1.) Use polymer gloves while being in any contact with hazardous chemicals
...
```

Now the user of the program would simply do a query on "handling harmful chemicals" and the program should give him the above two options as

1. CA) The operator must use synthetic gloves to handle chemicals
2. MN) Use polymer gloves while being in any contact with hazardous chemicals

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the major document management systems (e.g., [IBM FileNet](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/content-management/)) to see what they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicitly, you have at least five levels of "restructuring" to contend with.

1. How do I organize the collection of manuals from California?  (the corpus of documents)
2. How do I extract the text from a plain text file? HTML? a PDF? a Word document?  (document physical formats)
3. How do I recognize chapters, sections, headings, subheadings, captions, tables?  (semantics at the document level)
4. How do I parse plain text to extract meaning?  (semantics at the sentence level)
5. How do I deal with synonyms and whole-part relationships?  (ontology)

Your question implies some sort of sentence level semantics and ontological analysis when you recognize that "being in any contact with" has something to do with "handling."

You might look at [IBM's Watson project](http://www-03.ibm.com/innovation/us/watson/what-is-watson/science-behind-an-answer.html) for some ideas about how to extract meaning from a large body of data and some novel approaches to ontology.

How specific or generalized should your approaches be to these questions?  It depends, in part, on how bounded the corpus is.  Are you dealing with any document that shows up in a Google search for "chemicals," or just the publicly available documents from the California EPA?

Comment: Thanks@ David. I am thinking along the direction you have pointed me to. Nice explanation. I am looking for _publicly available documents from the California EPA_ etc.